# How (improve) updating multiple columns of a pandas dataframe, when the columns are datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has columns as datetime objects, and I would like to update specific values  for a specific index based on a list of *days*.

Here is an MRE that works:

```
import pandas as pd
start, stop = "2023-12-01", "2023-12-31"
dates: pd.Index =  pd.date_range(start, stop, freq="D")
december = pd.DataFrame(columns = dates, index = ['ft', 'pt'])
december.loc['ft', pd.to_datetime(['2023-12-04', '2023-12-06', '2023-12-11', '2023-12-12', '2023-12-27', '2023-12-28'])] = 'X'
```

In this example, I update the columns for the following dates:

```
['2023-12-04', '2023-12-06', '2023-12-11', '2023-12-12', '2023-12-27', '2023-12-28']
```

But ideally I would pass a list of days like `[4, 6, 11, 12, 27, 28]` to the `.loc` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do that using the [`day`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html) attribute and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
december.loc['ft', december.columns.day.isin([4, 6, 11, 12, 27, 28])] = 'X'
```

If you also only want to target december (or a list of months):

```
december.loc['ft', (december.columns.day.isin([4, 6, 11, 12, 27, 28])
                   &december.columns.month.isin([12])
                   )] = 'X'
```

Output:

```
   2023-12-01 2023-12-02 2023-12-03 2023-12-04 2023-12-05 2023-12-06 2023-12-07 2023-12-08 2023-12-09 2023-12-10 2023-12-11 2023-12-12 2023-12-13 2023-12-14 2023-12-15 2023-12-16 2023-12-17 2023-12-18 2023-12-19 2023-12-20 2023-12-21 2023-12-22 2023-12-23 2023-12-24 2023-12-25 2023-12-26 2023-12-27 2023-12-28 2023-12-29 2023-12-30 2023-12-31
ft        NaN        NaN        NaN          X        NaN          X        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN          X          X        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN          X          X        NaN        NaN        NaN
pt        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```